# Is there an equivalent method of `onListItemClick` when using BaseExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Suppose I have a list of items in some some `CustomActivity` class and processed by some `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. Is there any `onListItemClick` equivalent method ? More precisely, I want some method as such

```
 public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        SparseBooleanArray checkedPositions = l.getCheckedItemPositions();
...
```

(In my `ide`, this method seems to be not recognized)

Answer (score 0):

An `ExpandableListView` is a `ListView` that has groups and each group has children. For this reason it exposes a [`setOnChildClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnChildClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener%29) and [`setOnGroupClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setOnGroupClickListener%28android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener%29). Each of those methods exposes what you need:

`OnChildClickListener` has a `onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)` method.

`OnGroupClickListener` has a `onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id)` method.

Comment: thank you but how can I retrieve the whole the checked items from one group. As `l.getCheckedItemPositions();` in my question ?

Comment: What is each child showing? A checked button and you would like to have what?

Comment: How are you backing up your data? Usually for an `ExpandableListView` I am keeping a `LinkedHashSet` of keys to a `List`. If I want to get the group, I am iterating through keys. And if I need the whole list of children for a group then `map#get(key)` provides the whole list. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes exactly, I store my data in some `HashSet`. Here suppose I have  group whose key is `first`, and I want to get all the checked items in once. Is it possible ?

Comment: Well, a `HashSet` is not a `Map` so you don't seem to have a correct backed data structure. How are you providing the correct `ExpandableAdapter` callbacks? What are you really storing in the `HashSet` ?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, my `ExpandableAdapter` implements some HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map

Comment: You mean it uses (it has created such an object), not implements.

Comment: You need to make use of a `LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` since you're accessing the group name by index, not by value. And `LinkedHashMap` allows you to iterate though keys and once the iteration step is at specified `index` then you got the group. `HashMap` doesn't keep the keys order. You can call `keySet` but the  insert order is not preserved.

Comment: Here is [a link to help you find the best collection](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=65) in general.

Comment: Thank you for the link ;) But suppose I use `LinkedHashMap` to store data, how can I get all the checked items in once. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, as said, it is possible. Post the code of your adapter and I'll try to help ...